# Python connetion to smtp port 465 server fails

Tags: python, smtp

here is my script:

```
import smtplib
from socket import gaierror

port = 465 
smtp_server = "my_server.com"
login = "my_login_name.com"
password = "my_pass"

sender = "my_email.com"
receiver = "receiver_email.com"

message = f"""Subject: Hi Mailtrap
To: {receiver}
From: {sender}

This is my first message with Python."""

try:
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.login(login, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

    print('Sent')
except (gaierror, ConnectionRefusedError):
    print('Failed to connect to the server. Bad connection settings?')
except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
    print('Failed to connect to the server. Wrong user/password?')
except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
    print('SMTP error occurred: ' + str(e))
```

I am trying to send simply e-mail, but I got back message: `Failed to connect to the server. Wrong user/password?`. I guess there is some problem with connection to server. Port number, SMTP server address, login and password are correct. I also tried to use my google e-mail account and google SMTP server, but answer the same. What is missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ssl
smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host,465)

Comment: Just to emphasize, `SMTP` (usually on port 25 or 587) is unencrypted (though you might then be able to pivot to an encrypted connection with the `STARTTLS` ESMTP command) whereas port 465 is generally encrypted with TLS (aka SSL) and requires `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` instead of `smtplib.SMTP`